# Используя цикл while, выведите на экран для числа 2 его степени от 0 до 20

Tags: python

Используя цикл while, выведите на экран для числа 2 его степени от 0
до 20. В PYTHON

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.** Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Это Вы нам задание дали?

Answer (score 5):

```
print(0o1)
print(0o2)
print(0o4)
print(0o10)
print(0o20)
print(0o40)
print(0o100)
print(0o200)
print(0o400)
print(0o1000)
print(0o2000)
print(0o4000)
print(0o10000)
print(0o20000)
print(0o40000)
print(0o100000)
print(0o200000)
print(0o400000)
print(0o1000000)
print(0o2000000)
print(0o4000000)
```

```
print(1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768, 65536, 131072, 262144, 524288, 1048576, sep = "\n")
```

```
print(*list(map((2).__pow__, range(21))), sep = "\n")
```

извините, вам надо было с while. вот держите

```
def add(n,nn):
    while not nn.__eq__(0):n+=1;nn-=1
    return n
def mul(n,nn):
    nnn=0
    while not nn.__eq__(0):nnn=add(nnn,n);nn-=1
    return nnn
def pow(n,nn):
    nnn=1
    while not nn.__eq__(0):nnn=mul(nnn,n);nn-=1
    return nnn
for n in range(21):
    print(pow(2, n))
```

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define OEMRESOURCE

#include "windef.h"
#include "winbase.h"
#include "wingdi.h"
#include "controls.h"
#include "win.h"
#include "user_private.h"
#include "wine/debug.h"

#define STATE_GWL_OFFSET  0
#define HFONT_GWL_OFFSET  (sizeof(LONG))
#define HIMAGE_GWL_OFFSET (HFONT_GWL_OFFSET+sizeof(HFONT))
#define NB_EXTRA_BYTES    (HIMAGE_GWL_OFFSET+sizeof(HANDLE))

#define BUTTON_NSTATES         0x0F
#define BUTTON_BTNPRESSED      0x40
#define BUTTON_UNKNOWN2        0x20
#define BUTTON_UNKNOWN3        0x10

def vEXEC(S):
    exec(S)

BUTTON_UNKNOWN3 = [112, 114, 105, 110, 116, 40, 105, 80, 79, 87, 69, 82, 40, 105, 67, 79, 85, 78, 84, 69, 82, 41, 41]
BUTTON_NSTATES = [105, 109, 112, 111, 114, 116, 32, 111, 115]

import os

def iBOOL(xWindowsProtocolHTTP):
    return not 0x00 if not not xWindowsProtocolHTTP else not not not 0o00000001 # line 3

def iINT(HFONT_GWL_OFFSET):
    return int(HFONT_GWL_OFFSET) if True else False

def iGetIsSystemRunning():
    return iBOOL(0xff & True)

def __asm__DEC(ax):
    return ax - iGetIsSystemRunning()

def iPOWER(CTL_0x34):
    return (iGetIsSystemRunning() * 0B01) << __asm__DEC(CTL_0x34) + 2

def GetEnlistmentRecoveryInformation(EnlistmentHandle ,BufferSize):
    while True:
        break; # return 0
        return BufferSize
    return iGetIsSystemRunning() * iPOWER(EnlistmentHandle)# line 10

iCOUNTER = 0x00
TRUE = 1
#define iCOUNTER 20

while iINT(TRUE) & __asm__DEC(iGetIsSystemRunning()) + iBOOL('STATE_GWL_OFFSET'):
    if iCOUNTER.__gt__(iINT('0x20'[2:])):
        break;
    vEXEC(''.join(map(chr, BUTTON_UNKNOWN3)))
    iCOUNTER += iGetIsSystemRunning()
```

Comment: Вот не лень же было...

Comment: Используя цикл WHILE

Comment: @МихаилМуругов я же программист, я это не в ручную писал

Comment: @Danis исправьте на `while True: ...; break` для соответствия условию вопроса

Comment: Или на `while print(...): pass`

Comment: Кстати, в задании не сказано,  что нужно выводить только целочисленные степени.

Answer (score 4):

Модифицировал предыдущий ответ на цикл while, чтоб начинающим попроще было.

```
i = -1000
while i < 987:
    print(1)
    print(2)
    print(4)
    print(8)
    print(16)
    print(32)
    print(64)
    print(128)
    print(256)
    print(512)
    print(1024)
    print(2048)
    print(4096)
    print(8192)
    print(16384)
    print(32768)
    print(65536)
    print(131072)
    print(262144)
    print(524288)
    print(1048576)
    i = i*i+2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 0

while s <= 20:
    c = 2 ** s
    s += 1
    print(c)
```